# PostGIS-enabled Postgres DB JDBC Query Stuck in SQLException.setNextException

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgis

I am currently running a PostGIS-enabled Postgres database with the following version string:

```
Version string  PostgreSQL 9.4.1 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit
```

The JDBC driver I am using to connect is

```
9.4-1201-jdbc41
```

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

The schema for 'foo' is as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE foo
(
  gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('address_gid_seq'::regclass),
  objectid numeric(10,0),
  house_num integer,
  half_add character varying(4),
  pre_dir character varying(2),
  st_name character varying(50),
  st_type character varying(4),
  suf_dir character varying(2),
  unit_type character varying(4),
  unit_id character varying(6),
  city character varying(15),
  state character varying(2),
  zipcode numeric(10,0),
  angle numeric,
  parcel_num character varying(11),
  idnum numeric(10,0),
  status character varying(1),
  status_dat date,
  esnnum character varying(5),
  geom geometry(Point,3857),
  CONSTRAINT address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
```

I did not create this table, so I am not sure what may have gone wrong, but the count of the rows (done as a shortcut using pgAdmin3) is ~250,000, so there is demonstrably data in there. Asking to get some of the data via a 'limit' works, although it is incredibly slow.

I can pause my query in a debugger, which pauses in the following stack:

```
PSQLWarning(SQLException).setNextException(SQLException) line: 294  
PSQLWarning(SQLWarning).setNextWarning(SQLWarning) line: 213    
Jdbc4ResultSet(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet).addWarning(SQLWarning) line: 2669    
AbstractJdbc2ResultSet$CursorResultHandler.handleWarning(SQLWarning) line: 1841 
QueryExecutorImpl$3.handleWarning(SQLWarning) line: 2179    
QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(ResultHandler, int) line: 2023 
QueryExecutorImpl.fetch(ResultCursor, ResultHandler, int) line: 2201    
Jdbc4ResultSet(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet).next() line: 1924
```

I don't really have a ton of time to learn everything about how Postgres' JDBC driver is implemented, so I thought I shout out and see if anyone else has experienced this and if there is something wrong with the data in the table.  If I had access to the source data, I might be able to fix it on that end; but it seems strange that a query against an existing Postgres table would result in what seems to be an infinite loop.

I should add that ResultSet.next() never steps in the debugger, the code just stays in the setNextException() method indefinitely.

EDIT: 
I am getting tons of this in the "messages" in pgAdmin:

```
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_get_type:50] entered
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_set_srid:1455] entered with srid=3857
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_is_empty:1233] lwgeom_is_empty: got type Point
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwgeom_to_wkb:710] WKB output size: 25
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwgeom_to_wkb:723] Hex WKB output size: 51
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_is_empty:1233] lwgeom_is_empty: got type Point
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:393] Entering function, buf = 0x2acec3c3e770
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:395] Endian set, buf = 0x2acec3c3e772
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:integer_to_wkb_buf:189] Writing value '536870913'
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:398] Type set, buf = 0x2acec3c3e77a
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:integer_to_wkb_buf:189] Writing value '3857'
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:403] SRID set, buf = 0x2acec3c3e782
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:ptarray_to_wkb_buf:360] Writing point #0
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:ptarray_to_wkb_buf:364] Writing dimension #0 (buf = 0x2acec3c3e782)
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:ptarray_to_wkb_buf:364] Writing dimension #1 (buf = 0x2acec3c3e792)
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:ptarray_to_wkb_buf:369] Done (buf = 0x2acec3c3e7a2)
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:407] Pointarray set, buf = 0x2acec3c3e7a2
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwgeom_to_wkb:759] buf (0x2acec3c3e7a3) - wkb_out (0x2acec3c3e770) = 51
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_get_type:50] entered
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:lwgeom_from_gserialized:1137] Got type 1 (Point), srid=3857
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:lwgeom_from_gserialized_buffer:1091] Got type 1 (Point), hasz=0 hasm=0 geodetic=0 hasbox=0
```

`client_min_messages` is showing no setting.

Comment: Looping through 250,000 rows isn't inifinite but might feel like it!

Comment: It looks like something must be sending a *lot* of `WARNING` or `NOTICE` or similar messages on the wire. Check `client_min_messages`, and see if when you run it in PgAdmin or psql you get lots of messages. Hard to imagine how, really, since a `SELECT` from a simple table shouldn't be able to run any code that can emit notices. Are you *sure* the stack corresponds to that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is as mentioned in the comments:

Set `client_min_messages` to `ERROR`.  This will avoid shipping a dozen error messages to the client over JDBC per geometry record, which will increase the performance by at least an order of magnitude in my case.